# In a Multi-level Bayesian Hierarchical Model, would higher level parameters be affected by how they are jointly modeled in lower levels?

Tags: bayesian, multilevel-analysis, prior, hierarchical-bayesian

Suppose we have a Multi-level Hierarchical Model where:

$$
\begin{equation}
Y_{0i} \sim Bin(\theta_{0i}, n_{0i}) \\
Y_{1i} \sim Bin(\theta_{1i}, n_{1i}) \\
\theta_{0i} \sim Unif(0,1) \\
log\left(\dfrac{\theta_{1i}}{\theta_{0i}}\right) \sim N\left(\mu, \sigma^2\right) \\
\mu \sim N(0, 0.1) \\
\sigma^2 \sim Gamma(1,1)
\end{equation}
$$

and another Hierarchical Model that is **almost** the same except for how the $\theta$'s are jointly modeled:

$$
\begin{equation}
Y_{0i} \sim Bin(\theta_{0i}, n_{0i}) \\
Y_{1i} \sim Bin(\theta_{1i}, n_{1i}) \\
\theta_{0i} \sim Unif(0,1) \\
\theta_{1i}-\theta_{0i}\sim N\left(\mu, \sigma^2\right) \\
\mu \sim N(0, 0.1) \\
\sigma^2 \sim Gamma(1,1)
\end{equation}
$$

I understand that inferences on the marginal posterior of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ will be different in both models. However, will the marginal posterior of $\theta_{1i}$ and $\theta_{0i}$  be different or will they be the same? It seems that since for example, $P(\theta_{1i}|Y)$ can be obtained by marginalizing out $P(\theta_{1i}, \mu, \sigma^2|Y)$, then it is the same. But is this the case?

Comment: The second model is not compatible with the $\theta_{ij}$'s being probabilities and both models are incomplete because the joint on $(\theta_{0i},\theta_{1i})$ is not fully specified.

Comment: @Xi'an Sorry, I meant to model the control theta as a uniform, I've made the edit. When I use the second model, RJags appears to accept it. Is it perhaps simulating many times until a usable $\theta_{1i}$ (such that $\theta_{1i}-\theta_{0i}$) is retrieved?